# Mobile firefox click and hold events

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, events

I am trying to make simple webapp where an element can be clicked or hold to call different function.

```
$(document).on("click",'.element', function() {
    clickFunction();
});
let timeoutId = 0;
$(document).on('pointerdown','.element', function() {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(holdFunction, 500);
}).on('pointerup pointerleave', '.element', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
});
```

And it was tested and worked fine on Chrome, Firefox and mobile Chrome.
The problem is that on mobile Firefox the 'pointerdown' event is not called at all and i don't really know why.

Comment: Try using `mousedown`/`mouseup`/`mouseleave` as well

Comment: This may help: https://pawelgrzybek.com/whats-the-deal-with-the-pointer-events-in-javascript/

Comment: I just added mousedown next to pointerdown and it is not working as I intended. While i hold element still nothing happens and when i simply click element both click and hold actions are called

Comment: @Stuart turned out it was super usefull resource :D as far as i tested the touchstart event on browsers that don't suport pointer event is working fine. Thank you very much

Comment: That's great news @user3102664. Maybe you could add an answer to your own question, it may well help people in future :)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that mobile firefox browser is not supporting pointer events.
To check if browser supports pointer events simply use

```
if (window.PointerEvent)
```

On mobile firefox one should use touch events (touchstart, touchend, etc.)

It is also worth mentioning that if you don't want to call *holdFunction* while **holding element and scrolling** the the same time, the code for pointer events given in the question will work fine but when using touch events you probably will need additional check if window was scrolled

```
$(window).scroll(function(event){clearTimeout(timeoutId);});
```